# Recognizing and Replacing values matlab

Tags: matlab

So I have a certain grayscale image as a binary file. After I red in the image, I tried to create a series of "if" loops in order to replace a range of values with one value, and leave the rest of the matrix untouched.

I used this code

```
if myimage < 20 
    myimage = 0;
else if 20 < myimage <40
        myimage = 20;
    else if 40 < myimage < 60
            myimage = 40;
        else if 60<myimage<80
                myimage = 60;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

but for some reason it failed to load an image. After some debugging I figured out that the file was becoming a 1 x 1 matrix with the value "20" after the "else if 20...." line. Can anyone help me figure out why exactly this is happening? thanks.

Comment: The variable `myimage` is a matrix of values, and what you're doing here is treating it as a scalar. Your comparison expressions and assignment statements are not doing what you expect them to do. Instead, you want to find the indices of certain elements, and change only them. You should read more about [matrix indexing in MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html) and work your way from there.

Comment: So ill need to loop through the image and then do something like myimage(X,Y) < 20?

Comment: Yes, that's a good start.  For your case, think about something like this: `20*floor(myimage/20);`, which can process the entire image at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the specific indices in myimage that have a specific value. The way your currently calling it, you're overwriting the myimage variable with a specific value. One way to find all the relevant indices is with find:

`find(myimage==20)`

in order to find and replace all the values with a one liner, reference the indices of interest in myimage:

`myimage(find(myimage<20))=0;`

and to combine multiple sets of indices (eg values >20 AND <40), use intersect:

`myimage(intersect(find(myimage>20),find(myimage<40)))=20;`

Comment: As @EitanT's comment above shows, the call to `find` inside the indexing is redundant.

Comment: What would be the correct call in the case of two simultaneous conditions, eg myimage>20 AND myimage<40?

Comment: Something like `myimage(20<myimage & myimage<40)` but I suggest you follow the link that EitanT referred OP to.